# How do you test your Perl module to check if Makefile.PL declares all dependencies?

Tags: perl, testing, module, release, cpan

I would like to write a `t/00-check-deps.t` module to find all dependencies in `MyModule.pm` and make sure they exist in `Makefile.PL` before release.

This way when I do `make test` before distributing to CPAN I will know that nothing was forgotten prior to publishing.  I've looked at the [ExtUtils](https://metacpan.org/dist/ExtUtils-MakeMaker) suite, but I've not seen anything obvious that already solves this.  It seems like a common issue people would want to solve.

How would you do this?

Comment: Tool/library recommendations are off-topic *ach[Module::ScanDeps](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::ScanDeps)?oo*

Comment: @ikegami, I'm _not_ asking for a tool/library requirement, I'm asking _how it should be done_!  But thanks for the libr<sneeze>ary hint :)

Comment: So you're saying you're expecting us to write said tool? Also off-topic (too broad). SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @ikegami, *sigh*, no not wanting you to write the tool... just looking for how it might be done.  Maybe its off topic, but it seems like there is somewhere in the grey area that might be on-topic.  shrug.

Comment: Well, it has to be one or other, or a mix of both. You either need to use a pre-existing solution or create a new one. There's no other way. And both are off-topic for the reasons explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.  Thanks @ikegami for the [scandeps hint](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::ScanDeps):

```bash
find lib -name '*.pm' | xargs scandeps.pl -R | \
  perl -MJSON -le '
    undef $/; 
    %d=eval(<STDIN>);
    $j=JSON::from_json(`cat MYMETA.json`); 
    foreach (keys(%d)) {
      warn "Missing: $_ => $d{$_}\n" if !defined($j->{prereqs}{runtime}{requires}{$_}) 
    }
    '
```

prints:

```
Missing: Carp => 1.42
Missing: PDL::Constants => 0.02
Missing: Exporter => 5.72
Missing: constant => 1.33
Missing: PDL => 2.080
Missing: PDL::LinearAlgebra => 0.35
Missing: PDL::Ops => undef
```

Comment: Not quite.  Consider the situation if you have `Foo => 1.0` and there's a dependency on `Foo => 2.0`